# How to test timers mixed with async/await in javascript

Tags: javascript, async-await, jestjs

I'm trying to use Jest to test some async javascript code with a timer in it, but not sure the best approach to take. My code under test:

```
async function makeStartedProcess() {
    const extProc = await startExternalProcess();
    while (await isProcessStarting(extProc)) {
        await new Promise(r => setTimeout(r, 1000));
    }
    return extProc
}
```

My goal is to have the test exercise the loop by having the `isProcessStarting` method change behavior, so my test is something like this:

```
beforeAll(() => {
    jest.useFakeTimers()
})

test('loop', (done) => {
    startExternalProcess.mockResolvedValue({ foo:1 })
    isProcessStarting.mockResolvedValue(false)
    makeStartedProcess().then(p => {
        expect(...)
        done()
    })

    expect(isProcessStarting).toBeCalledTimes(1)
    isProcessStarting.mockResolvedValue(true)
    jest.advanceTimersByTime(1200)
})
```

The issue as I see it is that the await statements in my method under test are causing that method to be broken up into essentially 3 (or maybe 4) micro tasks, so things in my test method aren't executing at the time I'd need them to.

I can't help feeling though that I'm simply taking the wrong approach to this. What is the right way to do this?

Comment: Are you also mocking `startExternalProcess`? Without, you can hardly know when to switch the `isProcessStarting` to return `true`.

Comment: Yes - post updated to reflect this